# angular: enable strict mode for es lint

Tags: angular, typescript, eslintrc

I am really struggling with documentation on es lint config:
https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/configs/
Currently I have following settings in eslintrc.json

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "warn",
    // "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "warn",
    // "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "warn",
    // "no-empty": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error", { "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": false }],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which works but I would like to be more strict so I considered changing mode *stylistic-type-checked*
but I don't get what I need to change config to.
Documentations suggests for example this config for *Projects With Type Checking*:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/stylistic-type-checked',
  ],
};
```

or for *strict-type-checked*:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/strict-type-checked'],
};
```

I noticed that in the first example `eslint` is set to *recommended* rather than *recommended-type-checked* Apparently the addition type checks come from plugins which I find a little bit confusing.
Notice that in the second example there is no `eslint` value at all - now I am lost.

I tried almost all combinations but at the end the changes broke es linting completely.
How do I set this up?

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.1
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.1
@schematics/angular             13.3.10
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.9.5
```